# How to Create Video OCR?

Tags: image-processing, ocr

I am working in win form C# application.
Application grabs the images from video device like (TV/Camera or input video file).
Then processed it and save it in the text document.

My question is, "How to create Digital Video OCR ?"

please suggest me any tutorial/link/source code.

Answer (score 3):

Google Cloud provides video OCR API. https://cloud.google.com/video-intelligence/docs/text-detection

You can directly call this API with your video. It will return text bounding box and it's timestamp associated with your video.

Answer (score 1):

Start with the [tesseract-ocr .net engine](http://code.google.com/p/tesseractdotnet/) for the OCR part and [Emgu CV](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) for the camera methods. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Since Video OCR is still an active research topic, you may need to pay more effort to develop your own Video OCR Engine. Basically a Video OCR Framework can be built based on Video scene cut detection, Text detection and recognition from Video Cuts.

Using scene Cut detection as a preprocessing step to reduce the computation costs; then localize the Position and boundary of Text Content in Video Cut Frames; separat Text Pixels from the Background by using proper Text segmentation and binarization techniques. Finally one could apply print OCR engine to get Text result.

If you just process small amount of video data, you can use the [free video OCR rest API](https://www.mashape.com/semamediadata/video-ocr) on mashape.

Answer (score 0):

In case you or anyone else is working on this, I found [this site](https://waldo.jaquith.org/blog/2011/02/ocr-video/) to be very helpful.
Basically, a video is converted to still images, those images are processed to optimize OCR results, and then each image is OCR'ed.

Answer (score 0):

Some of this previous work might be relevant:

- OCR from Video Stream of Book Flipping (https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6778296)
- Video OCR for Video Indexing, Sankirti S. and P. M. Kamade (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1109.6862.pdf)
- Video OCR API (https://rapidapi.com/SemaMediaData/api/video-ocr)